# Combine Pandas Series 1 and Series 2 of different length, according specified index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, addition

I have two Series with different length:

S1 -> from `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` with index from 0 to 9;

S2 -> `[2,4,8]` with index specifically equal to `[4,7,8]`;

I need to add elements of S2 to S1 specifically at position `[4,7,8]`.

Ideally S3 should look like this:

`[1,2,3,4,7,6,7,12,17,10]`.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

S1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
S2 = np.array([2,4,8])

S1 = pd.Series(S1)
S2 = pd.Series(S2, index = [4,7,8])
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma OP is not looking for an `update`. He wants to `add` both the `Series` where `index` matches.

Comment: @Tommy yes you are right i misread that part.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
S1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
S2 = pd.Series([2,4,8], index = [4,7,8])
```

first `reindex` the `S2` series

```
S2 = S2.reindex(range(10)).fillna(0)
```

then `add` `S1 + S2` and assign to `S3`

```
S3 = S1 + S2

print(S3)

0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     4.0
4     7.0
5     6.0
6     7.0
7    12.0
8    17.0
9    10.0
```

If you're looking for an `integer` list. Then,

```
S3 = np.array(S3, int)

array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  6,  7, 12, 17, 10])
```

or you can straight away convert `S2` to `int` before adding.

```
S2 = S2.reindex(range(10)).fillna(0)
S3 = S1 + np.array(S2,int)
```

EDIT :

as per the comment by @ShubhamSharma

```
S2 = S2.reindex(S1.index, fill_value=0)
S3 = S1 + S2
```

Comment: Tommy instead of using `range(10)` you could also use `S2.reindex_like(S1)` or `S2.reindex(S1.index)`  optionally you can also pass `fill_value=0` in `reindex` method like `S2.reindex(S1.index, fill_value=0)` :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thank you for sharing this. great to know :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma added an EDIT incorporating your suggestions. :)

Comment: here is one more idea if index of `S2` is subset of `index` of `S1` we could also directly use `Series.add` here like `S1.add(S2, fill_value=0)`

Comment: I thought this was a simple question and solution. But, now I see, there's a wealth of knowledge behind this. Thank you again.!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update S1 series just run this:

```
S1.iloc[[4,7,8]] = S2
```

Comment: OP is not looking for an `update`. He wants to `add` both the `Series` where `index` matches.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured out by myself:

```
S3 = S1+S2
S3 = S3.fillna(value = S1)

print(S3)
```

Thank you all for your efforts and time.